# Where to set height of jquery revolution slider 5.3?

Tags: jquery, slider, height, responsive

I am not able to figure out - Where to set height of jquery revolution slider 5.3 ?

I have seen all the demos by themepunch and many HTML templates but no luck.
(Those I found less height were either 1. old versions, or 2. not working or 3. were non-responsive)
I need 500px height in a fullwidth revolution slider...must be fully responsive.

Any help with example will be appreciated. Note: I am not looking for old version example...as I already have them working.I need latest version only (above 5 version of Jquery Revolution Slider).

Answer (score 11):

In the constructor you can add **gridheight** to adjust the height of the four different responsive levels

```
$("div").revolution({
    // ...
    responsiveLevels: [1240, 1024, 778, 480],
    gridwidth: [1240, 1024, 778, 480],
    gridheight: [500, 500, 500, 500]
    // ...
});
```

https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/responsive-setup-2/

You can use [this](http://rsvisualeditor.themepunch.com/) to try it

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* initialize the slider based on the Slider's ID attribute */
$('#rev_slider_1').show().revolution({
    delay: 5000,

    /* options are 'auto', 'fullwidth' or 'fullscreen' */
    sliderLayout: 'fullwidth',
    autoHeight: 'on'
});
```

autoHeight: on makes the slider resize proportionally.  Otherwise it maxes out at 500px;

Hope that helps.

Aaron